# What is going wrong in my code when I increase the values that the for loops start and end with?

Tags: java

This is Project Euler's Problem #4

I was able to get the same solution that they give when they first present the problem. (The  the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.) However, once I try to do it for three digit numbers, I get nothing displaying in the console.

So when I start the loops with `for(i = 10; i < 99; i++)` and `for(j = 10; j < 99; j++)` I get to the solution 9009. However, that is not the case when I change it.

Here is my code:

```
public class LargestPalindromeProduct {

public static String reverseNumber(String x) {

    String number = x;
    String numberReversed = new StringBuffer(number).reverse().toString();

    return numberReversed;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

//A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

//Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers. 

    int x = 0;

    for(int i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {

        for(int j = 100; j < 1000; j++) {

            x = i*j; 

        }


        if((String.valueOf(x)).equals(reverseNumber(String.valueOf(x)))) {

            System.out.println(x);

        }



    }


  } // close main
} // close class
```

Comment: Isn't it possible that there are no palindromic numbers who are product of two 3-digit numbers?

Comment: (BTW: You put the if statement outside of the inner `for`.)

Comment: @GáborBakos It still works when I do it for 2 digit numbers though. (Although it lists all of the palindromic numbers within that range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your problem in the end of the inner loop

```
for(int i = 100; i < 1000; i++) {

        for(int j = 100; j < 1000; j++) {

            x = i*j; 

        if((String.valueOf(x)).equals(reverseNumber(String.valueOf(x)))) {

            System.out.println(x);

        }///the end loop here
}
```

Comment: Why did it work for 2 digit numbers then? I am just curious why the code format worked for that scenario and now I have to change it for the three digit numbers.

Comment: For 2 digits, the last number for `j` was `99`, so there is nothing surprising that `9009` was found. It worked because the `x` was always overwritten for new values.